# How to use HttpClient in a Razor component?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, razor, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly

I want to create a Blazor component library for my Microservice app and I have an issue on the login.razor component :

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject HttpClient HttpClient
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

<div class="container">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center" style="padding-top: 50px;">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="card px-4 py-4" style="border-radius: 0;">
                <form @onsubmit="SubmitForm">
                    <div class="form-data">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="identifiant" class="form-label">Identifiant</label>
                            <input style="background-color:#f0f6f7; border: 1px solid #f0f6f7;" type="text" class="form-control" @bind="@identifiant" placeholder="Identifiant">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="mdp" class="form-label">Mot de passe</label>
                            <input style="background-color:#f0f6f7; border: 1px solid #f0f6f7;" type="password" class="form-control" @bind="@password" placeholder="Mot de passe" autocomplete="off">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-4 text-center">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark mt-4">Connexion</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private string identifiant;
    private string password;

    private async Task SubmitForm()
    {
        AuthentificationRequest request = new AuthentificationRequest();
        request.Identifiant = identifiant;
        request.Password = password;
        request.Roles = new List<string> { "" };
        AuthentificationResponse resp = null;
        var response = await HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<AuthentificationRequest>("http://localhost:8001/api/Account/", request);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthentificationResponse>(result);
        }
        var httpContext = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        httpContext.Session.SetString("Identifiant", resp.Identifiant);
        httpContext.Session.SetString("JwtToken", resp.JwtToken);
        var jwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadJwtToken(resp.JwtToken);
        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(jwt.Claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes((double)resp.ExpiresIn)
            };
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Index");
    }
}
```

Nothing append and I don't know why.
When we validate the form I need to send a request to the authentication api to check password/id and access. Afterthat the api send back a jwt token and we need to create a session for the connection inside the asp.net app.

```
@page "/connexion"
@using Commons

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor

<div>
    <component type="typeof(Login)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</div>
```

I've try to see if something is send by httpClient but nothing appear inside the development console.

-- EDIT --

- HttpClient is defined in Program.cs like this :

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
```

- I don't see any request to my api inside google chrome console network

Comment: It seems like a CORS issue, can you put a breakpoint after the response to see what's inside ?
What's the status code of the response ?

Comment: I've tried to put a breakpoint but It doesn't stop. Maybe it's because the program doesn't go inside SubmitForm() function or it's because the razor code comming from another project (project reference) @halonico

Comment: Ok I tried the exact same code, and it works on my end.
For me, it has something to do with the <component> that might break the SignalR connection.
Instead of using <component> from Common, can you invoke the component directly in the view like that <Login></Login>

Comment: I tried to put <Login></Login> but there is nothing on my page. Maybe it is because it's inside a .cshtml file and not a razor one. Thank you for your answers @halonico. I don't see the form.

Comment: From my end, I tried the same thing as you did, with the _Host.cshtml with the <component type="typeof(Login)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />, and it works fine
Thus, I don't know what is happening, I'll still think about it and I'll come back

Comment: You mean it's sending fine a request? Because It's look like when I validated the form it's reloading the page but doesn't execute the function. Or maybe I don't see the request send and I've receiving an error but idk how to check that @halonico

Comment: I'm using a different API and I'm using a POST like you, it's weird that it's not able to call the method.

I wonder if there is a script that intercept the normal behavior of a form before blazor does its magic

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms/?view=aspnetcore-8.0&preserve-view=true

Use an EditForm to see what happens, if you don't find a solution and nobody finds the issue, that's my discord halonico#5835

Comment: Thank you, I will continue to work on and contact you if I don't get any other answer or if I don't find something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add below line in your client project It will work.

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://xxxxxxxx/") });

Let me know if you need any more details.